# Where could I find sha1 fingerprint in nativescript android app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I getting error while using firesbase login with google

```
JS: Make sure you've uploaded your SHA1 fingerprint(s) to the Firebase console
JS: Has the SHA1 fingerprint been uploaded? Sign-in status: Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this page to generate the SHA1 codes you need.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Then in the Firebase console on the settings general tab there is a spot labeled: "SHA certificate fingerprints"  where you can paste the fingerprints and save them.

Remember once you do this you need to download the google-services.json file and put it in app/App_Resources/Android folder.

Comment: where i need to put this command ? > keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: I run it from the command line in the base of my NS project, I don't think it matters as long as your paths are correct.

Comment: i was struck with wrong android keystore password. finally i got it. Thanks Man